# How to plot a pandas series as horizontal lines?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

short_run = df["High"][df["Volume"] >= df["Volume"].quantile(0.999)][1:22]

short_run.plot()
plt.show()
```

Output of `short_run`:

```
1012     0.000189
1013     0.000167
11696    0.000096
25019    0.000075
25020    0.000076
25071    0.000077
25072    0.000078
25073    0.000081
25079    0.000085
25080    0.000089
25081    0.000090
25083    0.000095
25084    0.000099
25085    0.000117
25086    0.000106
25087    0.000103
25088    0.000100
25089    0.000090
25090    0.000092
25092    0.000089
25093    0.000086
```

Which outputs the following diagram:

[image: output]

I was wondering how instead of getting a line plot I could instead get a bunch of horizontal lines (which intersect the y-axis based on the values of `short_run`). In other words how can I turn the previous diagram into this one:

[image: desired output]

*(PS: I don't need the red line, I just included to make it easier to understand)*

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @roganjosh oops, thanks for pointing it out. yes, it's horizontal lines that I looking for. (I updated my question)

Comment: It's just 22 numbers, can you include `short_run` in the question?

Comment: @QuangHoang Thank you  for the reply, I just updated my questions with the values of short_run

Answer (score 0):

You failed to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Since I do not have your DataFrame, I can tell you an *indirect* solution.

The idea is to get the axis instance returned by the `df.plot` and then get the y-data. Then, loop over the values and plot a horizontal line at each of them. To hide your actual red line, the easiest thing to my mind is to use white color **again since** you did not provide any reproducible code

```
ax = df.plot(color='white')
line = ax.lines[0]
for y in line.get_ydata():
    plt.axhline(y)
```

Alternatively, assuming your y-values are in a variable `y_val`, you do not need to first plot the DataFrame. You can directly use `matplotlib` as

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for y in y_val:
    plt.axhline(y)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, It doesn't seem to work (I don't get any errors but the graph get loaded for hours, without actually beeing loaded)

Comment: I've updated my question with the values of `short_run`.